# IISExpress shows up as host for browser in Visual Studio and messes up everything - how to get back to local?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

All of a sudden after I installed Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 gd, Visual Studio is using IIS Express when debugging a web application and it is messing up everything.

How do I get back to normal, so that stupid IISExpress is not used anymore?

[image: Image clarifying the problem]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project settings and on the web tab is a drop down that allows you to choose which engine to use.

[image: Project settings]

Answer (score 0):

I went to Project > Properties > Startup Project and then set my start up projects to start the services I need and my project. This reverted my button back to just "Start".